Как отсортировать файлы по id
Всем привет! Все никак не могу разобраться, у меня есть файлы с названием 1-1000000.txt
Мне их надо отсортировать по 30.000 в каждую папку, то есть 1-30.000 папка 0, 30.000-60.000 - папка 1 и т д. У меня только приходит на ум прописывать руками if, elseif, ну это бред и при увеличении количества файлов будет необходимость прописывать. Просьба помочь советом, спасибо!

делишь общее количество на то, сколько надо пихать в папку, округляя результат в большую сторону (ceil)..... Дальше цикл от 0 до этого числа.....пихаешь по 30 к

Т.е. задача состоит в том, чтобы имя превратить в число? Число потом можно разделить на 30000 и получить номер папки.
